# Swift 2.0 + Alamofire 3.0 - slow loading of JSONs

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a project for showing healthy recipes. That project returning JSON object from Alamofire to Arraylist and then to Table Cell in Tableview. When I am loading all the objects to tableview it loads ...well slow. 8+ seconds. But my target is 3  seconds. I know the problem is around alamofire cause I check print(timestamp). Anything i am doing wrong?

```
func getCookData(urlString: String , completionHandler: (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String) -> ()) -> (){



    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON() {
        response in
       // var cookArray:[CookData] = []

            if response.result.isSuccess {
            let data = response.result.value

            let cookJson = JSON(data!)

            for (var i = 0; i < cookJson["data"].count; i++){

            let category = cookJson["data"][i]["kategorie"].stringValue
            let nameOfRecipe = cookJson["data"][i]["nazev"].stringValue
            let preparationTime = cookJson["data"][i]["priprava"].stringValue
            let cookingTime = cookJson["data"][i]["vareni"].stringValue
            let dificulty = cookJson["data"][i]["obtiznost"].stringValue
            let count = cookJson["data"][i]["pocet"].stringValue

            var ingredience = String()

            for var j = 0; j < cookJson["data"][i]["ingredience"].count; j++ {

                let ingredienceX = cookJson["data"][i]["ingredience"][j].stringValue

             ingredience = ingredience + "\n" +  "- " + ingredienceX

            }

            let nutriInfo = cookJson["data"][i]["nutricni_informace"].stringValue
            let kcal = cookJson["data"][i]["nutricni_informace"]["Kcal"].stringValue
            let bilkoviny = cookJson["data"][i]["nutricni_informace"]["Bílkoviny"].stringValue
            let sacharidy = cookJson["data"][i]["nutricni_informace"]["Sacharidy"].stringValue
            let tukyy = cookJson["data"][i]["nutricni_informace"]["Tuky"].stringValue
            let preparationMekanism = cookJson["data"][i]["postup_pripravy"].stringValue
            let photo = cookJson["data"][i]["photos"][0].stringValue
            let thumb = cookJson["data"][i]["thumb"].stringValue

            self.printTimestamp()

            completionHandler(category, nameOfRecipe, preparationTime, cookingTime, dificulty, count, ingredience, nutriInfo, preparationMekanism, photo, thumb, kcal, bilkoviny, sacharidy, tukyy)
            }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: If loading is slow, slow is your internet connection :) If the treatment is slow, it is a programmation or a hardware problem. Can you be more precise ? Simulator type, iOS target, your own mac model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... The answer is simple, the data I wanted to load was too much and I did (even the unused **data**). The ideal way to solve this is to only GET what you need and then become very specific.

EXAMPLE:** I have a **Recipe Book**. I want to get all the recipes and watch them. 
SOLUTION: so get only ID and name of all recipes and store them in an **array**, then of you need specific recipe to be shown, write an `Alamofire` method to get that specific recipe data and call it with the ID of that recipe parameter.